# Ide attempts to load package from a wrong location

Tags: delphi, package

I've made a little design package and installed it in the ide (delphi XE8).

This package defines a new kind of button to be used on Intraweb forms.
I've compiled and installed successfully the component, and tested it with a test application.

It all works perfectly.

Then I have a big application, made of several packages belonging to a project group, in which several pages use such a new button.

Sometimes (not always), as I open the project group of my app,
the ide complains that it cannot find my package.dcp, but it tries to open it
from the desktop  (c:\users\maurizio.ferreira\desktop\newbutton.dcp) instead of opening it from where it resides  (C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\Dcp\newbutton.dcp)

When this happens, I have to close the projet group, 
reopen the component project, build and reinstall it, 
close it, reopen my project group.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

**!!!! I've found it !!!!**

I had a package (newbutton.pkg) with THE SAME NAME OF A UNIT (newbutton.pas)
contained in the package.

(THIS SHOULD BE FORBIDDEN, OR, AT LEAST, RAISE A WARNING).

This confuses the IDE when I open a project that uses such a component.

I solved the problem renaming, rebuilding and then reinstalling the package.